# How to make Docker build to use cache from a previous job?

Tags: angular, docker, gitlab-ci

I have a Node.js application that I want to containerize in Gitlab CI/CD.
This app includes a git submodule containing its Angular front-end.
Before proceeding with the "docker-build" job, the front-end must be generated.

My idea was to add a dedicated stage in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that will generate the front-end in a cached "fe" directory:

```yaml
  stages:
    - front-end
    - build
    - test
    - package-build

  front-end:
    stage: front-end
    image: "registry.hub.docker.com/trion/ng-cli-karma:latest"
    script:
      - npm run fe-install
      - npm run fe-build
    cache:
      paths:
        - fe
```

But, how to get this cached "fe" directory in subsequent "docker-build" job so that Dockerfile can copy the front-end into the container?

I forgot to mention that "docker build" job is provided by imported file from "to-be-continuous" framework. I guess this is important to notice

Comment: I eventually found the solution I was looking for.
Instead of
````
front-end:
...
  cache:...
...
I had to declare 'fe' as artifact for this job so that susequent jobs can use it
...
front-end:
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - fe
...

Answer (score 0):

I consider you can use the artifacts keyword in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`. This way you can get the cached `fe` directory in subsequent `docker-build` job.

Updated file:

```
stages:
  - front-end
  - build
  - test
  - package-build

front-end:
  stage: front-end
  image: "registry.hub.docker.com/trion/ng-cli-karma:latest"
  script:
    - npm run fe-install
    - npm run fe-build
  cache:
    paths:
      - fe

docker-build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:latest
  script:
    - docker build -t your-image-name .
    - docker create --name dummy your-image-name
    - docker cp dummy:/your-path-to-fe /path-in-container
    - docker rm -v dummy
  dependencies:
    - front-end  
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - fe/
```

Comment: Hello. My bad, I forgot to mention (I have edited the request now) that "docker build" job is provided by imported file from "to-be-continuous" framework. I doubt I can overwrite imported job in mt YML file :-(